# Positioning in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, circles

I'm trying a very simple use of tikzpicture for drawing an ellipse. My problem is that when I change the coordinates -- say from `(0,0)` to `(10,0)` -- nothing happens, i.e., position of the ellipse does not change. Any ideas why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and .5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The posisioning in tikzpicture is relative. You have to give one point as base (lets say in a `\path` command) so that the next point will be moved relative to your start point. See my example.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

According to my comment: "the posisioning in tikzpicture is relative. You have to give one point as base (lets say in a \path command) so that the next point will be moved relative to your start point."

Test code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and .5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){};
\draw (5,3) ellipse (2cm and .5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the first image the minimum x= -2 and maximum =2 from the ellipse.
In the second the ellipse starts from x=(5-2)=3 and ends to x=(5+2)=7, but xminimum=0 from the `\node` command, so the ellipse will be moved 3 cm right. Also ymin=0 (from the node) but ellipse is between y=(3-0.5)=2.5 amd y=(3+0.5)=3.5cm...

Hope that explained what you need.

Output:

[image]

So, a good practice is to use empty nodes in xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax and then everything will be as expected. (a rectangle path like `\path (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);` would be a shorter and better option if you are familiar with that.)

Comment: You are welcome @Asaf. If your question is answered, please accept the answer you prefer by clicking the tick on its left.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thin,xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \draw (1,1) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```